# unix 'ls' command with wildcard input - equivalent in java 6

Tags: java, unix, wildcard, ls

I need an equivalent behaviour in java for this command in Unix cli:

`ls /data/archive/users/*/*.xml`

Which outputs me:

`/data/archive/users/2012/user1.xml

/data/archive/users/2013/user2.xml`

Is there a simple equivalent implementation for Java 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I used, it works with relative and absolute paths:

```
DirectoryScanner scanner = new DirectoryScanner();  
if (!inputPath.startsWith("/") || inputPath.startsWith(".")) {  
    scanner.setBasedir(".");  
}  
scanner.setIncludes(new String[]{inputPath});  
scanner.setCaseSensitive(false);  
scanner.scan();  
String[] foundFiles = scanner.getIncludedFiles();
```

(DirectoryScanner from org.apache.tools.ant)

Answer (score 2):

Get user input using [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and use [`java.io.File.listFiles(FilenameFilter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) method to get the list of files in the folder with specific filter.

Comment: It's not so easy to parse for ex. path: "/data/*/users/*/*.xml". Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, and it's called the `list` method of the `File` class. See it's [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I forget where this came from but this should be a good start. There are many more available via [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Java+RegexFilenameFilter).

```
public class RegexFilenameFilter implements FilenameFilter {
  /**
   * Only file name that match this regex are accepted by this filter
   */
  String regex = null; // setting the filter regex to null causes any name to be accepted (same as ".*")

  public RegexFilenameFilter() {
  }

  public RegexFilenameFilter(String filter) {
    setWildcard(filter);
  }

  /**
   * Set the filter from a wildcard expression as known from the windows command line
   * ("?" = "any character", "*" = zero or more occurances of any character")
   *
   * @param sWild the wildcard pattern
   *
   * @return this
   */
  public RegexFilenameFilter setWildcard(String sWild) {
    regex = wildcardToRegex(sWild);

    // throw PatternSyntaxException if the pattern is not valid
    // this should never happen if wildcardToRegex works as intended,
    // so thiw method does not declare PatternSyntaxException to be thrown
    Pattern.compile(regex);
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Set the regular expression of the filter
   *
   * @param regex the regular expression of the filter
   *
   * @return this
   */
  public RegexFilenameFilter setRegex(String regex) throws java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException {
    this.regex = regex;
    // throw PatternSyntaxException if the pattern is not valid
    Pattern.compile(regex);

    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Tests if a specified file should be included in a file list.
   *
   * @param dir the directory in which the file was found.
   *
   * @param name the name of the file.
   *
   * @return true if and only if the name should be included in the file list; false otherwise.
   */
  public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    boolean bAccept = false;

    if (regex == null) {
      bAccept = true;
    } else {
      bAccept = name.toLowerCase().matches(regex);
    }

    return bAccept;
  }

  /**
   * Converts a windows wildcard pattern to a regex pattern
   *
   * @param wild - Wildcard patter containing * and ?
   *
   * @return - a regex pattern that is equivalent to the windows wildcard pattern
   */
  private static String wildcardToRegex(String wild) {
    if (wild == null) {
      return null;
    }
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    char[] chars = wild.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
      if (chars[i] == '*') {
        buffer.append(".*");
      } else if (chars[i] == '?') {
        buffer.append('.');
      } else if (chars[i] == ';') {
        buffer.append('|');
      } else if ("+()^$.{}[]|\\".indexOf(chars[i]) != -1) {
        buffer.append('\\').append(chars[i]); // prefix all metacharacters with backslash
      } else {
        buffer.append(chars[i]);
      }
    }

    return buffer.toString();
  }
}
```